# How can I change or edit the markup of leaflet map's popup?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I see this HTML inside div.leaflet-popup:

```
<a class="leaflet-popup-close-button" href="#close">×</a>
```

Is there a way to use a different markup for the close button? for example:

```
<span>Close</span>
```

I prefer not to write custom javascript for this purpose.